# Best practices to keep strings in one place

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm setting up a new iOS project and wondering if I should use a `Localizable.strings` file to keep my strings even without planning to add support for other languages.

I've tried using struct to keep my strings before but I am wondering if this is a good practice. Using `Localizable.strings` will also work well on the library [`R.swift`](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift), another reason why I am struggling to choose a strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "best practice" in this case. There are practices and some may be a bit more appropriate for your case than others.

You are saying that you are not planning to add support for other languages but it seems like you want to be prepared for it if you change your mind. So first thing is to ask yourself what is the actual problem you are looking solution for. I would say the problem is the overhead you get once app is already out and you need to hunt all the strings you have used in your app and wrap them into `NSLocalizedString`. This usually includes endless testing and you will still in the end most likely forget to localize at least some strings.

You can from beginning start wrapping things into `NSLocalizedString` which will in the end help you extract all the strings using native tools from your code. The problem then are still Storyboards; not as much extracting strings from storyboard but removing those default texts you have no plan to translate (Like "Name" will actually be some name and should not be translated). So in my experience this is a half solution.

To solve the Storyboard issue there should be a tool (I can't remember which, maybe some other CocoaPod) which enables you to ignore views that should not be translated. So in this case you need to use 2 things; `NSLocalizedString` and ignoring untranslatable items in IB.

As you already put it nicely you can use R.Swift to get strings directly from your `strings` file. This is very neat but also extremely distracting as you develop. Doing so you are forcing developer to first enter a text in `strings` file before he can use it. Personally I hate that. Also this can be a problem with multiple developers being in conflict. Not to mention this hasn't nearly fixed your issue with Storyboards.

Creating a separate structure system to hold all the strings does work pretty nicely. You don't have to hunt down all of the strings in your code and you don't need to jump to `strings` file (going to another source is much more pleasant when developing since you can navigate to it very easily). You do also preserve a good structure, assuming you maintain it like `label.text = Strings.Settings.User.firstNamePlaceholder` which helps you to easily find strings you need or are deprecated. You can remove whole screens with great ease. But it still is an overhead for developer plus you still have an issue that now you need to drag all the outlets from storyboard to set the localized strings to them.

Doing this procedure you can in the end choose to use `NSLocalizedString` directly or to use R.Swift. In fact you can just use nothing and you will still not have much overtime switching to any of the two (again assuming that hunting down those strings in the code takes most of the time).

Personally I would go with nothing at all or go with creating a custom structure system which then uses nothing but just returns raw strings. But this all really depends on what size is your project of, what type of project, how many things are in Storyboards... It also depends on when you expect to have more resources so you either spend more time now and don't bother later or you simply do it simplest now prepare for a lot of work when localization is indeed needed (hopefully when that happens it is one of the "sweet" problems because it means you have tons of users).

Comment: In this custom structure, how will you handle 10 languages? you do a switch ?

Comment: @iosMentalist You do not handle languages in custom structure, 10 languages are still in your 10 .strings files. The benefit of custom structure is mostly that you can neatly nest your properties and don't bother with duplications, renaming and so on. You would still use `let firstNamePlaceholder = NSLocalizedString("my_key_here")` and then let your system resolve `NSLocalizedString("my_key_here")` with any of 10 languages.

Comment: makes sense. So correct me if I'm wrong,  your statement regarding R.swift : "Doing so you are forcing developer to first enter a text in strings file before he can use it" apply for all cases you mentioned .

Comment: @iosMentalist Not in case where you make your own structure. When having your own structure you can easily do `let firstNamePlaceholder = "First name" // TODO: localize` at development time. Then later on your can go through all of these strings, input them in .strings file and then replace this code with `let firstNamePlaceholder = R.string.translations.userSettings_firstName_placeholder()`.